# How to import navigation in WebView component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

i stuck with one case in React Native. I have this components:
[image]

This is my App file..where my set i want to start with WebViewScreen, i still did not set useState etc.
My Navigation component:
[image]

And my WebView component:
[image]

So i have one question. How i can use navigation in WebViewScreen, when this component is outside of NavigationContainer. Some people will tell to import WebViewScreen as Stack.Screen .. okey but in my site where i have inputs and after click keyboard should up on Android when i click input keyboard up, refresh and hide..I need to use navigation, because with changeNavigationState i want to handle when user click on Login button, to redirect to my Native Login Screen. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Theres is NO way you can use any navigation method from react-native-navigation outside of their own provider (NavigationProvider). If you want to use navigation on your WebviewScreen, you HAVE TO place it in a stack screen. Besides from that, anything else would be BAD PRACTICE. If this answer is not enough pls explain why you can't place the WebviewScreen in your NavigationContainer cause this is the real problem then.

Comment: Everything works when i use WebView in Stack.Scree and click on some textinput..keyboard shows and refresh and hide..But now i fixed i changed navigation from Stack to Native-Stack and now works fine, but i am not sure really why and what is the difference..